# No type named 'type' in 'struct std::common_reference<Ref&&, const Val&>'

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to write a proxy iterator using Boost.STLInterfaces.
It fails to compile because the lvalue reference of the value and the rvalue reference of the reference are different, see a simplified version on Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/z/aE3bq7en4.
How do I make two types have common reference?
I tried overloading the addressof operator to return the reference type, but compiling a distilled example

```
#include <type_traits>

class Ref {};
class Val {};

// overload addressof operator
constexpr Ref operator&(Val) noexcept;
constexpr Ref operator&(Ref) noexcept;

int main()
{
  std::common_reference<Ref&&, const Val&>::type t;
  return 0;
}
```

fails with

> error: no type named 'type' in 'std::common_reference<Ref &&, const Val &>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to partial specialize [`std::basic_common_reference`](https://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.other#7) to define the *common reference* of the two, similar to this:

```
template<template<class> class TQual, template<class> class UQual>
struct std::basic_common_reference<Ref, Val, TQual, UQual> { 
  using type = Val;
};

template<template<class> class TQual, template<class> class UQual>
struct std::basic_common_reference<Val, Ref, TQual, UQual> { 
  using type = Val;
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/4d7PbWY3E)

Some issues worth noting:

- `Val`'s member functions need to be `public`.
- `Val`'s constructor should not be `explicit` to satisfy `indirectly_readable`.
- `Val`'s `operator=(Ref ref)` needs to return `Val&` to meet `sortable`.
- `Ref` needs to add `operator=(Val) const` overload to satisfy `indirectly_writable`.

Comment: Are the operator& still needed? It does compile without them.

Comment: @SD57. It depends on your needs. But IMO, their existence does not make sense.

Comment: The demo doesn't compile with clang-11. Does the demo rely on something that clang does not support yet? One of the unsatisfied constraints is
`no member named 'begin' in 'View'`
which seems incorrect.

Comment: Clang is not yet compatible with libstdc++'s `<ranges>`.

Comment: Why is the type is the basic_common_reference type is the value type, not the reference type of the proxy iterator? Seems counterintuitive. And it doesn't compile the other way around.

Comment: Maybe it can be too. But the point of the answer is that you need to use `basic_common_reference` to define `common_reference` for custom types.